# how can I see grossing apps in iPhone app store?

Tags: app-store, itunes

When I check app-store in iPhone, I can only see the free-apps and paid-apps but appannie.com and similarweb.com presents grossing-apps also. I wonder that how can I see grossing-apps in iPhone app-store. Do you have any suggestion? Or any trick?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible for iOS-10 or older versions. New versions don’t provide grossing-apps.